# Method not Behaving for Unknown Reasons

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So, I'm making my own implementation of a Binary Search Tree. In doing so, I've come across an unusual issue, and I have no idea why it's occurring.

**setNode Method:**

```
// Sets the Node at the specified Index
public void setNode(int index, NodeInterface<E> node)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= degree)
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size: " + nodes.size());

    nodes.set(index, (Node<E>) node);
}
```

The variable *nodes* is an Array List of Nodes, if that is important.

Now this is where things begin to get messy, being where the error is occurring. It's in the *addDescendant* method within the *BinaryNode* Class, which extends the *Node* class.

**addDescendant Method:**

```
// Adds the specified Descendant to this Node
public boolean addDescendant(BinaryNode<E> node)
{
        // Determine Node Type
        if(compareTo(node) > 0) // Make Left Child
        {
            if(hasLeftChild())
                return getLeftChild().addDescendant(node);
            else
            {
                setNode(0, node); // Link Parent to Child
                // ^^^ Works Fine ^^^
                node.setNode(1, hasRightChild() ? getRightChild() : this); // Link Child to Parent or Sibling
                // ^^^ Does not Work ^^^

                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(compareTo(node) < 0) // Make Right Child
        {
            if(hasRightChild()) // Node already has a Right Child
                return getRightChild().addDescendant(node);
            else // Node does not have a Right Child
            {
                if(hasLeftChild())
                {
                    getLeftChild().setNode(1, node); // Link Sibling to Sibling
                    // ^^^ Does not Work ^^^
                }
                else
                {
                    setNode(0, node); // Link Parent to Child for the time being
                    // ^^^ Works Fine ^^^
                }

                node.setNode(1, this); // Link Child to Parent
                // ^^^ Does not Work ^^^

                return true;
            }
        }
        else // Duplicate Node
            return false;
    }
```

The two important things to note here are the uses of the *setNode*. It works fine when I use the index of 0, but doesn't work when I use the index of 1.

I'm not getting any errors or warnings, and the code seems to run as it should, but the results are not what I'm expecting.

The method doesn't set the Right Node properly, despite it using the same method to set the Left Node, and that works fine.

I hope I've given enough information, I didn't want to bombard everyone with code.

**Unrelated Note:**
If you're confused by the connection of my tree, that's because it's not your typical Binary Search Tree. However, the actual structure of the tree shouldn't matter.

Comment: Homework?   I notice your addDescendant code is asymmetric - the 'left child' clause is not similar to the 'right child' clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information. But I will try:
I think you tree is more unary than binary.
If an index of 1 marks the right child of a node
but also marks the parent of a node, the logic seems
somehow broken to me.

Second thing is in the 'Make left child' part of `addDescendant`:
It can happen that that more than 2 nodes have the 'root' node
connected to their index 1.

At 'Make Right Child' part of `addDescendant`:
`getLeftChild().setNode(1, node);`
Changing nodes of child nodes without further checkings
(by not-using its `addDescendant` method) is not a good idea.

Comment: The left and right pointers do not point the same node all the time. Where they point can differ. The left pointer always points to a child. If there are two children, then it points to the left child. The right pointer points to a sibling (if the node itself is a left child), or it points to the parent (if it is a right child). You basically get a triangle like structure from this. It's similar to a threaded tree.